# Anagrams of two strings

Tags: c

Write C a program to find whether the 2 given strings are anagrams or not.

Input consists of 2 string. Assume that all characters in the string are lowercase letters or spaces and the maximum length of the string is 100.

Sample Input and Output 1:
Enter the first string
anitha
Enter the second string
amphisoft
anitha and amphisoft are not anagrams

Sample Input and Output 2:
Enter the first string
the eyes
Enter the second string
they see
the eyes and they see are anagrams

Sample Input and Output 3:
Enter the first string
dormitory
Enter the second string
dirty room
dormitory and dirty room are anagrams

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_anagram(char [], char []);

int main()
{
   char a[100], b[100];
   int flag;

   printf("Enter first string\n");
   gets(a);

   printf("Enter second string\n");
   gets(b);

   flag = check_anagram(a, b);

   if (flag == 1)
      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are anagrams.\n", a, b);
   else
      printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are not anagrams.\n", a, b);

   return 0;
}

int check_anagram(char a[], char b[])
{
   int first[26] = {0}, second[26] = {0}, c = 0;

   while (a[c] != '\0')
   {
      first[a[c]-'a']++;
      c++;
   }

   c = 0;

   while (b[c] != '\0')
   {
      second[b[c]-'a']++;
      c++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      if (first[c] != second[c])
         return 0;
   }

   return 1;
}
```

I write the code but it was working only for first one input/output but second and third one input it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works. 
Since you are writing it works only for the first input, I'm guessing the problem was in the loop area which you removed to post the question.

One possible reason for it not to work after the first time, is not clearing a and b before getting new input.

Hope I helped,